Grab object corner to Move it, like in Rhino?
Coming back to Blender after years in Rhino, where your mouse can snap to a corner (or mid point, etc) of an object and Move it from there. Since Blender's cursor can snap to a corner, it stands to (my noobish) reason that our mouse could snap and grab to a corner, as well.
What I'm seeing in replies on other sites is:

You need to select the object, then Tab into Edit Mode
Select one of the corners
⇧ Shift + S ,  Cursor to Selected (2).  Tab out.
Object > Set origin > Origin to 3D Cursor.
⇧ Shift + S, Cursor to World Origin.
⇧ Shift + S,  Selection to Cursor.

Is this accurate?

Hi. You might want to look at these two sections of the Blender manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html  and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/transform/modal_map.html You might also look on YouTube. Maybe search for something like blender snapping.

In case anyone else comes from CAD, this is the video that explains how to easily select the object pick-point to move (in the example, he is able to select the base point of the back right foot of a dog model and snap it to the corner or mid-point of another object’s edge, etc.) It’s from almost a year ago, and you had to download a Experimental add-on, so I’m not sure if this has made it in as a basic feature or not (I’m not near my computer to check) Hope this helps some people. https://youtu.be/m5UvuJgZgP0?si=qu5anW3Kj9npeyS2
